# PHP Script to redirect with users input

Tags: php, redirect

I know that I can redirect to a website by using:

```
<?php header('Location: http://site/'); ?>
```

but how can I make it redirect to a variable value and make the redirect URI look like:

```
http://myURL.com/redirect.php?variable=http://redirect.com
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it with the URL parameters?

Comment: What do you mean. Sorry new to PHP.. `echo $_GET['link'];`?

Comment: Have you tried: `<?php header('Location: http://site/redirect.php?var=test'); ?>`. What else have you tried? What are you having an issue with... http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I want to be able to grab destination link of the redirect from user. so my redirect.php requires the varable=newsite.com in order to make it work. I just need to create a redirect script that works like http://myURL.com/redirect.php?variable=http://redirect.com

Comment: so you have `http://myURL.com/redirect.php?variable=http://redirect.com` as a variable and want to pull out the `http://redirect.com` section of it into a new variable? If so you want to look into using `explode()` or other alternatives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your page that asks a user for the URL:

```
<form action="redirect.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="url" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**redirect.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['url'])){
        header("Location: http://" . $_GET['url'] . "");
        exit();
    }
?>
```

**What this does**

When a user submits a form on your index page (or wherever you dropped the `<form>` code they are redirected to `http://yoursite/redirect.php` and the variable `url` is appended to the URL as such: `http://yoursite/redirect.php?url=THEURL` where "THEURL" in this example is the URL that the user typed in on the form.

Please note, this is nowhere near secure enough, not does it do any validation (which you should absolutely do).

Comment: Change the single quotes to double quotes like so `header("Location: $_GET['url']");` or this script is going to fail. No not like that. The other ones :P

Comment: Single quotes in that function will see any variable as plain text so that won't work either. You have to use double quotes on the function in this case, not the variable.

Comment: @icecub Okay, bed time I think.

Comment: Dangers of late night SO-ing without much caffeine!

Comment: To be honest, this isn't a very good way of doing this **but** it's what the OP asked for

Comment: @scottmcgready do you have another way of doing this? The provided script doesn't work by just accessing test.php?url=http://google.com

Comment: ah! It's a problem on my end. My apologies.

Comment: @user3610137 good stuff. If you feel my answer is useful and solved your question please do mark it as such.

Comment: @scottmcgready, Actually I am not able to do this. test.php?url=somesite.com

Comment: @user3610137 I've edited my answer but you're not listening to what I'm saying. `header('Location: somesite.com');` is malformed because there is no method (http, https) before the URL. Also check if headers are already being sent before as you cannot redirect after headers are sent.

Comment: Wait, do you actually have a redirect.php file? You keep taking about test.php?